# Cannot upgrade unlocked package: This app can't be upgraded

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package, trialforce

I'm trying to upgrade an existing unlocked package in an org.  The installer is complaining about a Lightning event:

> Cannot add component of type:AuraDefinitionBundle
>   named:ckz_StartingObjectSelectedEvent subjectId:0Ab6g000001QEys to
>   another package because it is an installed component.

As a test, when I try to delete the event in question in Dev Console, the only components that are mentioned as having a reference to the Lightning event are those in the package I'm trying to upgrade.  I also double-checked the other unlocked packages in the org, and they don't contain the Lightning event either. 
Has anyone else experience this issue?

**UPDATE**

The issue appears to be with creating a new org from an org that has been Trialforced.  The unlocked package can be upgraded directly in the Trialforce org no problem.  However, the new org created using the Trialforce Id does not list the unlocked package components:
[image]

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Yes.  Its a SF code bug, essentially.  This is currently being investigated by SF.